# Adding a gitignore file

Tags: git, windows-7, gitignore

I have a preexisting repo at C:\MyProject. It has a .git folder but I don't have a .gitignore. I created one with notepad (which says its a text document), and when I got to do a commit, the .gitignore folder got added to the repo.

How do I fix this?

I am using Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because your files are already being tracked,

[Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Comment: Whoops I looked at another stack answer like that but didn't see the . after git rm -r --cached . so it works now

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a file and a folder with the same path.  What is in the .gitignore folder?  This should be a file.